# jQuery - Keyboard shortcuts don't work until clicking into browser window

Tags: javascript, jquery

Working a on a little prototype for an interface concept. I decided to play with keyboard shortcuts a little and ran into a small snag. I'm not that proficient with jQuery or js for that matter.

**Issue:** The shortcuts `L` and `R` only fire once you have clicked into the window somewhere.

**Goal:** Have them work the second you load the page without click anywhere in the UI.

Codepen: http://codepen.io/darcyvoutt/pen/rhtfk

The actual code that needs review is as follows:

```
// Reveal Panel with Shortcuts
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).bind("keydown", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 76) { $('.panel-left').addClass('expanded'); }
    if (e.keyCode == 82) { $('.panel-right').addClass('expanded'); }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to open the page outside of the Codepen frame set. Codepen seems to grab the focus so it is not initially on your page, which is then changed by clicking it.

Works fine for me then.

Comment: Thanks, that was certainly the issue.